# Service layer in Architecture - DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, architecture

We're in a very early design phase of a medium/large scaled application in .Net, for a system that has three different clients (Sites) in-house (One in a separate domain) connecting, as well as a lot of external services.

We're focusing now on the in-house sites that connect, and I am proposing a classic layered app, with Interface layers, Service layer, business logic layer and a data access layer.

[image]

In the image, we have a Browser which connects to an MVC application. The Controllers have a reference to a Service project (The would have classes for each "Business Area" possibly. For example, "PersonService"). The MVC would have a direct reference to this service project. In the Service layer, there will also be some WCF projects, exposing certain functions to external sources, other internal sites and services etc.

The WCF projects though, would connect to the main Service DLL to get shared functionality from it.

The Service project then has a direct reference to the Business project, containing all business logic. It then has a reference to the Data Access project which has a/some Entity Framework models as an ORM for the SQL Server database.

The SharedLib is simply a project which all layers reference, containing any shared logic, but mainly for the DTOs (Data Transfer Objects). EF models are translated into DTOs in the Data layer, as no other layers have reference to EF models.

But MVC app, connecting to a service layer, via a direct reference within the application, as well as having WCF services exposed to external sources and cross domain internal sites.

The issue we're having is on the Service layer. I think this should be a DLL, where others say, if there is no WCF, then the presentation should connect direct to the business logic layer. They ask, 'Why add the extra layer and complexity of a service DLL here?'.

Is it good practice to eliminate the service layer where the presentation 'can' connect direct to logic? I see the benefit of the service layer adding a clear segregation of the business and the presentation, with expandability being allowed. It does seem like a pass through dll, but connecting to the BL directly seems - strange.

Is there a pro/con to using the DLL that would justify keeping/not keeping it?

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate a bit when you say "The issue we're having is on the Service layer. I think this should be a DLL". How do you intend to structure the solution? In your diagram, what is the shared library box, do you mean a "shared project" or a binary that is shared by different UI implementations?

Comment: Thanks @LostBalloon. Edited the questions.

Comment: If my answer is too long, feel free to skip some paragraphs or all the way to the last few. Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks @LostBalloon. No skipping required. Enjoyed the read. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see a hint to the MVVM pattern in the picture, I will assume it is the case, but it should not have a real influence on the answer.

I won't have the perfect answer, but do not think the business layer should be accessed directly.

I think any functionality the interface needs should be accessible through commands in the view-model which use the available services to perform their tasks.

The way I see it, the business layer would be business rules such as the formulas and budget mappings when creating an invoice. Another example generating a P.O. number.

On the other hand, The invoice service would be in charge of applying the different business rules you have in order to generate, modify, etc. (manage) your invoice.

What I often see happen when there is no need to make things too complicated is that the business layer will be implicitly contained within the service layer.

The biggest advantage of having the service layer compiled to DLLs is that they can be shared by the different parts of your app (front-end & back-end for instance). For instance, if you use ASP.net to build the front-end, it will be an advantage to be able to share the services, but if you go with something like angular.js then obviously they will not be usable making the library less desirable.

I also see a hint of WebAPI which is the newest trend to decoupling client interface from a server-based back-end. This pattern usually implies that the client doesn't know your business logic or much about your backend. Sends out an HTTP request in order to perform actions and the API responds with confirmation or data depending on the action (GET vs POST).

As for the WCF part I'm not too familiar with it, I personally use RabbitMQ.

All in all, I hope my rant gave you something to think about and helps you in your decision making.

Since it's a C# .net question, I guess I can safely assume it's your solution will be created in visual studio. Personally if there is enough of a purpose to separate the services from the business logic, I would not hesitate to add an additional library project to my solution and add the reference to the projects that require it. It doesn't add much overhead at all as most of it is managed by visual studio (or msbuild if in command line when automating builds).

As stated in the previous paragraph, I would create the library project in my solution as managing it is not too complicated & it will actually facilitate proper namespace management as a small bonus.

I don't think you guys should be scared of having more dll's (again depending on the scale of the project). If you think about it, every time you add a nuget package in your projects, you are essentially taking a dependency on another dll.

Comment: Thanks! The MVVM does show it's self here. It's more MVC, but as MVC uses "View Models", I think it is basically MVVM. I need to learn more about that. Your answer is what I was thinking. I like having the separation between logic, and presentation, allowing for a defined "Get all your services from me" type idea. As opposed to "Some from the Logic DLL and some from Service". Namespace is a good point! That gives me more ammunition. :) And the resistance I get, is the overhead of extra work of maintaining the DLL. But .. it's just a pass-thru, really, and to me, is very low overhead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to address anything above the service delivery layer; how you deliver the results of the service to a browser should be neutral in the design of the service layer. We currently use an entirely client side UI using AngularJS and it works incredibly well.

For me the point of having layers is mainly to permit abstraction and to allow the replacement of a layer with something else, or to revise the way that the layer is implemented without rewriting everything. So in my designs the layers that sit on top of each other; so the Service layer should only be using the repository, the repository is the only place that the domain model / core business logic is referenced.

I've been working on a fairly large system for the last 4 years. We started off using Windows Worfklow, WCF and MVC.Net. We stopped using Workflow and WCF after the first revision (roughly 6 months) - WCF was adding nothing but complexity and tedium to the coding. Workflow is still on our list for reinclusion once we figure out how to implement it correctly. We're using my [Emesary](https://emesary.codeplex.com/) messaging system within each DLL and also using the EmesaryMSMQ bridge to allow multiple machines to provide services. Emesary allows you to have an Interface based notification system within a project - and the bridge allows you to bridge certain notifications (reliably over MSMQ) to other processes. Whatever method you use it is extremely important to design your protocols correctly.

We have our own private nuget repository - and I wish we'd started off this way simply because it really focuses the design process and ensures replaceability. Currently we have a IUnitOfWork that is provided by an IUnitOfWorkManager and an IAuthorisationMediator that provides the [Reference Monitor](https://entitysecurity.codeplex.com/) based object level security. It took me a day or so to get used to using NuGet but it's a good investment.

Finally I'd advise against using EF. Although an extra cost I'd recommend using dataobjects.net (and I'm not affiliated in any way except as a very happy user). 
Initially we chose dataobjects.net because it was code first. I re-evaluated EF(code first), NHibernate and a few other ORM's in 2012 - and we continued to use dataobjects.net as it is the easiest to code for and has the best performance (for us). I don't want to wander off topic too much onto the subject of ORMs so I will conclude by saying that we recently used EF for another project - and we all wished that we'd not used it.

[image: Standard service design]

---

[1](https://emesary.codeplex.com/) We did realise at the time that it was partly promotional by the creators of dataobjects.net but our test results largely agreed with theirs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does EmesaryMSMQ compare to RabbitMQ? Does it also have handling of retries, errors & with an interface allowing you to resubmit messages back into the queue to be processed?

Comment: As for EF, I've used EF6 in a recent project and it does the job pretty well (I had an interesting learning curve though..) EF7 which is in development on github is supposed to be much better and will also support (more easily) having multiple data-sources (which was my biggest issue with EF6). I have to say my project was DB-first though.

Comment: Main problems with EF (which may have been resolved). Save Changes getting exponentially slower as you insert / modify more records. I found that about 300 was the optimum. Not assigning the ID (when autogenerated keys) until after save changes. Lazy loading being too lazy and requiring an Include. Lack of exceptions when mixing objects across different contexts. Database migrations are difficult to get right. Problems when two identical entities loaded separately from the context. Just lots of difficulties with EF where it doesn't work like I expected.

Comment: EmesaryMSMQ is a much lower level protocol than RabbitMQ; it's closer to ZeroMQ. Basically you send a message via a Transmitter that is then reliably delivered via MSMQ. That's all it does. Once the message has been received it is upto the recipient to handle any extra logic. Often the recipient would send a message back to indicate status. It's up to you to design a protocol. The elegance is in the simplicity; the originating objects do not need to know whether the notification is being routed or not and just send it in the same way as a locally handled message.